# Changing the location of the PHP error log file

Tags: php, iis, logging

I use PHP version 5.3.19, [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 Standard SP 1 and [Internet Information Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) (IIS) 7.5.7600.16385.

My problem:

I can't change the PHP error log file location.
When I try that and restart the IIS service, my web application cannot be opened:

> Browser says 500 - Internal server error.

I tried everything.

I checked the error logs of Windows and the IIS error log.
Nothing! Is this possible?

I was able to change the locations of the PHP session data folder and the PHP upload temp folder, no problem. (I created a folder, `C:\myapplication\mycompany\temp`, and gave this new folder all the necessary rights, so the IIS *IUSR* can do everything.)

So: The new locations of the PHP session data folder and PHP upload temporary folder work after restart of the IIS service! That's fine!

But I cannot change the location of the PHP error log file. Why?
It is the same new Windows folder having the ultimate rights.

I tested a little bit with different text files.
I created new and empty log files, tested with the original PHP error log file from *C:\Windows\Temp*. Nothing. And I really restarted the IIS service after every change of the *php.ini* file. But in the end: The browser says *500 - Internal server error* when browsing the web application.

So, what can I do? I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You may be setting the error logs in file *php.ini*.

Try setting it at runtime with something like:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('error_log', "C:\php\error.log");
```

That way, you should see the error message on screen, it there is one.

Comment: Hi, right: I did it in php.ini. The default value after installing php on iis/windows server was "C:\Windows\Temp". It's terrible, isn't it? I would like to move the log file into another folder, my own folder, where ich can change the IUSRs rights.

Comment: fantastic, help me troubleshoot an odd error on code that had been running over 4 years.

Comment: @peter-mortensen thanks for "improving" my answer. Truth is I'm glad I wasn't kicked out back then. It's a poor answer and there's no rephrasing that can fix that.